# Extend @PathVarible annotation to create a custom annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I'm trying to create an annotation to do some validations on path variables and I'm trying to combine @Pathvariable and my validations to a single annotation. this is to simplify coding and also to avoid the need for multiple decorations on path variables. is this possible to extend @PathVariable to create a custom annotation? thanks in advance for suggestions

Comment: did you try to add an AOP interceptor to do param validate?

Comment: Here is a link for defining custom annotations - good luck: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/annotations/complete-java-annotations-tutorial/

Comment: @PatrickChen no, interceptor will not work in my particular scenario unfortunately, I need it as a custom pathvairiable annotation with some validations

Comment: Examine (and perhaps subclass) `PathVariableMethodArgumentResolver`.